# Vim not behaving properly in ssh sessions spawned by Expect

Tags: unix, vim, expect

When I open the files in my redhat server vim is displaying something like this when I move the mouse down/up or when I go to insert mode and edit.
Also the contents inside gets jumbled up.

[image: Vim]

I also observed that it happens only when I ssh to server using my Expect script.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: That can happen due to network delays which interfere with vim reading the bytes of the cursor-keys fast enough.  (not a programming question).

Comment: Once thing I noticed is that, it happens only when I using expect script to login(automated login). When I normal login, it doesn't happen.

Comment: How about other termcap/curses or whatever applications. Like "Midnight Commander" or "htop". After login: What does `echo $TERM` print?

Comment: @user7369280 TERM prints xterm-256color

Comment: **`expect`** has to wait (just like **`vim`**) for the bytes in a cursor-sequence to arrive.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I am using it to login after that the last line is interact, it's handing over the control to me.

Comment: Is the issue with interact ? If I put exit in the last line, it logs out of the ssh session

Comment: Did you check `mc` (Midnight Commander), `top`, `htop`, man page viewer etc?

Comment: Please show your Expect script so others can help take a look.

Comment: try using `ssh -t` or even `ssh -tt`

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's caused by you resizing the terminal window after `interact`. According to the [Expect book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do), you can add the following code after `spawn`:

```
trap {
  set rows [stty rows]
  set cols [stty columns]
  stty rows $rows columns $cols < $spawn_out(slave,name)
} WINCH
```

---

[image: Exploring Expect]