# Close the expect script without closing the session in ssh

Tags: linux, unix, expect

I have an ssh script to sign in to my server

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn ssh rootacc@$ip

// logic to login

interact
```

The expect script would still be running. 
I need to close the expect script(kill) after the 'logic to login' is completed, without closing the ssh session.

If I replace 'interact' with 'exit' the session is being closed and it will return to my local file system.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the expect process is still running?

Comment: @glennjackman I have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055316/vim-not-behaving-properly-in-server
I thought it's due to expect script

Comment: See my comment on that question